# Linking Users table to other entities/tables

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I have a `data driven` `ASP` application. And like most `data driven` applications, i have a `Users` table and a `CreatedBy` field in most of the tables.

I am trying to create a `DeleteUserFunction` in my application. Before deleting any user i must check each and every table to see if that user has created any records.

Building relationships between the `users` table and the rest of database tables can make the `DeleteUserFunction` easier to validate.

Therefore, I am trying to figure whether a users table must be explicitly linked to other tables (via foreign key constaints) or must it be handle in application business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your functional requirements need to be clarified. What should happen if a user gets deleted?

```
1 User may not get deleted if records linked to her are present.
2 User may be deleted, and
  2.1 all records linked to her stay present, without link to that user,
  2.2 all records linked to her must be deleted as well.
```

A foreign key constraint can support 1 and 2.2, but not 2.1, because it won't change the user foreign key in the referring record.

However, using a foreign key constraint as the only way to enforce this might lead to strange software structure and user experience. In all cases, the violation of the constraint will be detected by the database, and will, by default lead to some exception in the data access module. But probably, you don't want your application to crash with an exception, but rather tell your user that this function is not available (in case 1) or trigger some application function (in cases 2.1, 2.2). This would mean passing the exception around in the software until the right layer to handle the case is reached.

Therefore, I'd recommend to perform the necessary checks to find out whether the deletion is legal and to trigger the logical consequences as part of the application logic. The foreign key constraint may still be useful as a way to detect application error during tests.

Comment: To clarify your question, if a user gets deleted only option number 1, as per above applies: `1 User may not get deleted if records linked to her are present.` Option 2.1 does not really make as there will be no way to figure out who the id belongs to.

Comment: Okay, so probably your users will like being told whether delete is possible before pressing delete and getting a message that they shouldn't have done so. That can only be done via application logic, as you need to hide or invalidate the delete button before any user action. You don't want to issue the delete on the database (triggering the foreign key exception) just to do this. So this calls for an application function querying the database for any present records for that user.